# How do I save an entity into another entity core data swift

Tags: core-data, swift2

So I have a Users Entity and a Hobby Entity, I have created the relationship of to-many where one User can have many Hobbies. I have created the inverse relationship as well. I have generated the subclasses for those entities as well but I am not sure how to save a Hobby entity into the User entity.

Here are my User subclasses:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Users: NSManagedObject {
// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}

import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Users {

    @NSManaged var password: String?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var hobby: NSSet?

}
```

Here are my Hobby subclasses:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Hobby: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}

import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Hobby {

    @NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

I have figured out how to add/update/delete items from core data but just not sure how to add a whole entity into another. Any help would be great! If I am doing something wrong or thinking about it the wrong way please correct me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create subclasses like in this example where relationship is to many. Subclass (Teacher/Course+CoreDataProperties.swift) looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Teacher {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var lastname: String?
@NSManaged var course: NSSet?

}
```

and this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Course {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var teacher: Teacher?

}
```

After that when you create teacher object or fetch existing one, and you create or fetch course object you can access course property "teacher" and set that like this (let‘s say that new course is math):

```
math.teacher = (here you add Teacher object that math course is related too)
```

Comment: Ok so I can add the whole Teacher object to math.teacher? I dont have to worry about the NSSet?

Comment: I used what you suggested but I'm not sure if it added the hobby to the user. I am not sure how to print the hobbies from the User entity where its an NSSet. Any ideas on how to loop through that?

Comment: Looks like that worked, another guy helped me print the data and your insert worked. So I just need to save to the inverse to make it work.

Comment: You can find and access coredata SQLite file (that one that is created on simulator) and open it with tool like SQLPro for SQLite. There you can see all informations about entities and connections between them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have left out some of the generated code, because there should be an inverse relationship in the Hobby class going back to the user(s).  I imagine the Hobby -> User relationship is also to-many because I'm sure the hobby of "Bird Watching" will have more than one user.

If your code does not include that relationship, then your model probably does not actually include an inverse relationship.

Also, it is more common to use the plural form for to-many relationships, which means you may want to consider renaming your relationship to "hobbies."

All you have to do is add a "Hobby" object instance to the "hobby" relationship for a given "user".  No need to change both relationships because core data will establish the inverse relationships.

This is a completely untested attempt at converting ObjC to swift, but it should be close enough for jazz.

```
// Add 'hobby' to the set of hobbies for a given 'user'
// The inverse relationship (add 'user' to the set of users for a given 'hobby'
// will be automatically handled by core data
user.mutableSetValueForKey("hobby").addObject(hobby)
```

**EDIT**

> Ok so I think I need to get current user to add to the correct user. I
>   am wanting to use something this code var curUser =
>   NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User",
>   inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Users curUser.hobby =
>   addHobbyTextField.text as! NSSet but not sure how to treat an NSSet.
>   Any help on that? – Suzukijak3

So, it looks like you are creating a new user...

```
var curUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
    "User",
    inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Users
```

The second part, however, is a bit confusing.  You wrote this...

```
curUser.hobby = addHobbyTextField.text as! NSSet
```

and I admit to knowing ZERO about swift, but that just looks strange.  You are trying to cast a string (the value inside a text field) into a `NSSet`?  That will never work, and it does not make any sense.

I'll guess what is in that text field is the name of a hobby, maybe something like "reading" and maybe you want to add "reading" as a hobby of the new user.

If that's the case, then you need to fetch the hobby object based on the hobby name, and then add that hobby to the collection of hobbies for the given user.

Now, I will depart from any pretense at swift and answer in ObjC because I imagine you as the swift programmer can port what I write here into appropriate swift better than I can and this seems to be more of a question of how to use core data than one of swift syntax (also, you probably do not want to merely ignore the possible error in the fetch).

```
// Fetch the appropriate hobby object
NSString *hobbyName = addHobbyTextField.text;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Hobby"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", hobbyName];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
Hobby *hobby = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL] firstObject];

// Add the hobby to the set of hobbies for this user
if (hobby) {
    [[user mutableSetValueForKey:@"hobby"] addObject:hobby];
}
```

Comment: Ok so I think I need to get current user to add to the correct user. I am wanting to use something this code `var curUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Users
        curUser.hobby = addHobbyTextField.text as! NSSet` but not sure how to treat an NSSet. Any help on that?

Comment: Ok thanks Jody, I will try that out. I can make that translation I think, I'll see if it works.